# Having Side Effect of Component State Multiplying after each Route Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm making a SPA Web Application for practice purpose but having trouble with React Rendering..My App usually has only two working routes **Home** & **Upload**. **Home** Route Fetches data from an API & displays it in the Body Component..With **Upload** I can upload products to the Database...Everything works fine except the Home Page...

#### *When I come back to **Home** from another route the previous state remains same but for some reason the state gets multiplied & evrything just gets doubled I mean the fetched data gets doubled..Please help me....*

**My App's Body Component where Fetched data is displayed**

```
//Importing Redux Action Creators
import {getProducts, deleteProduct} from "../Features/actions/productActions"
const Body = ({getProducts, deleteProduct, productState})=>{
    const {products, loading, error} = productState; //Destructuring redux State

     //Fetching data using redux actions inside useEffect hook
    useEffect(()=>{
    getProducts()
    },[getProducts])

    //Providing the payload as id for Redux Actions
    const deleteProducts = (id)=>{
        deleteProduct(id)
    }

    return (
        <div className="display-flex width-full flex-wrap justify-content-center">
            //Some Loading Logic for displaying data
            {!loading && !error && products?products.map(product=>(
                product.data?product.data.map(d=>(
                  //This is the component which displays the fetched data as bootstarp card
                    <BodyDiv
                        key={uuid.v4()}
                        imgSrc={d.imgSrc}
                        title={d.title}
                        details={d.details}
                        description={d.description}
                        onClick={()=>deleteProducts(d._id)}
                    />    
                )):product.map(d=>(
                    <BodyDiv
                    key={uuid.v4()}
                    imgSrc={d.imgSrc}
                    title={d.title}
                    details={d.details}
                    description={d.description}
                    onClick={()=>deleteProducts(d._id)}
                /> 
                ))
            ))
            : loading&&!error
            ? <div className="vertical-center-strict horizontal-center-strict">Loading.......</div>
            : <div className="vertical-center-strict horizontal-center-strict">No Internet!</div>
        }
        </div>
    )
}
//The layout for displaying fetched data
const BodyDiv = (props)=>{
    return(
        <div className="container-div width-full card tiny-padding align-self-start">
        <img title={props.title} className="img-responsive hover-filter" src={props.imgSrc}/>
        <h2 className="text-align-center">{props.title}</h2>
        <h5>{props.details}</h5>
        <p className="text-align-justify">{props.description}</p>
        <button 
        className="btn btn-danger"
        onClick={props.onClick}
        >Delete</button>
        </div>
    )   
} 
//mapping & dispatching state to props from redux
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>({
    productState: state.productState
})
//React-Redux Connect to connect the component with Store
const conn = connect(mapStateToProps, {getProducts, deleteProduct})(Body)

export default conn;
```

**My Redux State's Action Creators & Reducer**

```js
//Using redux-thunk for asynchronus middleware
export const getProducts = (payload)=>(dispatch)=>{
   return fetch("/api/products") //URL
    .then(res=>{
        dispatch({
            type:FETCHING_PRODUCTS //While fetching data
        })
        if(!res.ok){
            dispatch({
                type: ERROR_GET_PRODUCTS //If fetch fails then executes
            })
        }
    return res.json();
    })
    .then(json=>{
        if(json)dispatch({
        type: FETCHED_PRODUCTS,
        payload: json //Fetched json data as payload
    })
})
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log("Error!! failed to fetch data: "+ err)
    })
} 

//Reducer Function

//initial state
const initialState = {
  products: [], //this the state where Fetched data gets injected...
  loading: true,
  error: false,
};

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case FETCHED_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.concat(action.payload), //I don't know but I doubt here is the problem
        loading: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case ERROR_GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

**I believe that something is wrong with the useEffect() hook or Reducer Function**..Some people would say that I should try using ***products* state** as useEffect dependencie but that makes the situation worse...Please guys help me!!! I have been trying to fix this since 1 day...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes problems seems to be where you think it is

```
 return {
        ...state,
         // the problem is here, you are adding products when in reality you just be just replacing them
        products: state.products.concat(action.payload), //I don't know but I doubt here is the problem
        loading: false,
        error: false,
      };
```

replace this to

```
return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload
        loading: false,
        error: false,
      };
```

Comment: Actually, I figured it out while writting the post but I wasn't sure & I had other works too so  I didn't intend to solve it...but thank you! Because of you, I tried again & the issue got fixed

Comment: @KRTirtho marking it as resolved will help others, one they wont try to solve a question that was already solved, and two if someone was facing the same problem they can find the solution easer